# What is the correct pitch accent for めっちゃ?

Tags: pitch-accent

Based on 大辞林, the correct pitch accent for the word めっちゃ should be [1], めっちゃ{hlll}. However, this doesn't really seem to be how people actually pronounce it (Example [here](https://forvo.com/word/%E3%82%81%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83/#ja)). From the example, to me at least, it sounds more like めっちゃ{lhhh}. What exactly is the correct pitch accent for めっちゃ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it’s traditionally [1], and you do occasionally hear that accent even now, but it’s definitely a minority of people.

However, the current majority accent in Tokyo is [0] (borrowed from the Kansai accent, because that's where the word was most actively used before entering the Tokyo dialect).

In general, 大辞林’s accents are pretty traditional/old/outdated. 三省堂国語辞典 第八版 lists it as [0].